# (Magento) Shop by category shows other category description than category page

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

At the moment I have a strange thing in magento. When I click on a category from the menu I see a description mentioned for the sub-category. But when I click on the category from the "Shop By" menu. I see the text from the root category.

I've noticed that when I click from the topmenu, the link is http://example.com/rootcategory/subcategory/subcategory.html but when i click from "Shop By" the link will be http://example.com/rootcategory.html/?cat=13 . I think this caused the other description text.

Has anybody a solution to this problem? I've searched google for the answer but I couldn't find anything.

Thank you in advance.
Roy

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are still in the root category, it just filters the products by category. That is the way Magento's layered navigation works. To get rid of it, you can disable categories in the layered navigation and include a navigation block in the same place.